# HTAccess: Rewrite Subdomain to HTTPS Main site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I want to rewrite a subdomain to a folder in my main site.

For example, `test.example.com` --> `example.com/test`.

I only have an SSL (CA-verified) certificate for `example.com`, but not a wildcard certificate. So, `test.example.com` is encrypted but not verified. So, is it possible to rewrite `https://test.example.com` to `https://example.com/test`, while also maintaining verification? Or should I just use a redirect?

Currently, this is my folder structure:

```
.htaccess
public_html/ # this is the document root for example.com
    ...
test/ # document root for test.example.com
    ...
```

Comment: But `test.example.com` would already be loading content from `/test/` folder isn't it?

Comment: Well, my main goal was to allow my one SSL certificate, which is for my main domain, to work on subdomains as well.

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test)\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

This will redirect `test.example.com --> example.com/test`